# why spring-batch warn : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have an application with spring boot(1.4)  that use spring batch and spring data JPA.

At startup, I have this warning:

2017-03-07 08:51:53.324 WARN ---[           main]o.s.b.a.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer      :JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs

Is it still a problem since this [improvement](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5012)?

Comment: That fix is specific for hibernate not for every JPA provider out there. The spec basically doesn't allow so, so as long as the spec doesn't allow custom isolation levels this remains an issue.

Comment: @M. Deinum, thanks!